# how to add button in CruiseControl.Net UI

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I am new in CruiseControl.Net.i wanted to add one link "Download" in ViewFarmReport.aspx page.when i will click this download button it will download test.zip folder into my local system. test.zip is placed in same system "c:\myzipproject\test.zip" .

i have used below command but its not displaying in UI

```
<externalLinks>
        <externalLink name="IIS Root Web on Localhost" url="http://localhost/" />
        <externalLink name="Google" url="http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&amp;lr=&amp;q=%22CruiseControl.NET%22&amp;btnG=Search" />
    </externalLinks>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the CC.NET service for these changes to show up.
And do a iisreset (stop/restart IIS (www) service) to be sure.